# Add resource/import image to custom UserControl attribute in VS Designer via Dialog(s)

Tags: image, visual-studio, user-controls, resources, propertygrid

My aim is to create a custom control displaying some images, which can be added/exchanged by the user of that control. So, if it is added to a Form, the GUI designer should be able to change some or all images provided by the control editing the appropriate attribute.

In my Test-Project I have a simple control with 4 Attributes:

```cs
 public Image MyImage { get; set; } = null;
 public List<int> MyListOfInt { get; set; } = new List<int>();
 public List<Image> MyListOfImages { get; set; } = new List<Image>();
 public ImageList MyImageList { get; set; } = new ImageList();
```

Using this control in a Windows Form Project, clicking on

1. `MyImage` brings up the 'Select resource' dialog. OK
2. `MyListOfInt` brings up the 'Int32 Collection Editor' dialog. OK
3. `MyListOfImages` brings up the 'Image Collection Editor' dialog, but using 'Add' button shows message:

   > 'Cannot create an instance of `System.Drawing.Image` because it is an
   >   abstract class.'
4. `MyImageList` shows an emtpy list, which cannot be edited.

My question is, if it's possible to tell VS Designer to use the 'Select resource' dialog when clicking 'Add' button and what needs to be done?

Comment: Maybe this [Codeproject-Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got another answer from MSDN:
[How to edit UserControl attribute of type ImageList in Designer PropertyGrid (add/remove/exchange images)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d08577a-8e3f-4a22-b391-16da63ebd1c2/how-to-edit-usercontrol-attribute-of-type-imagelist-in-designer-propertygrid-addremoveexchange?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

I will describe the idea in short. First create a new control with an `ImageList` attribute.

```
public partial class NewControl : UserControl {
    public NewControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageList MyImageList { get; set; } = null;
}
```

1. Then drag this control on any form.
2. Additionally drag an `ImageList`  control from Toolbox onto this
   form - I called it 'MyImages'.
3. Edit `MyImages → Images` with designer.
4. Assign 'MyImages' to `NewControl`'s instance attribute `MyImageList` in property grid

[image: Edit MyImages]

The only drawback I see here is, that if the control already has an initialized `ImageList` attribute, the designer cannot handle it.  If you try to edit `MyImageList` before you assigned another list, the designer shows the controls default list, that comes with the control. But it's not possible to edit that list.

This solution is much easier to deal with and much shorter than the first solution above, so that I prefer it more.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Marwie's comment, I was able to solve the problem.

> There are three requirements that a collection should meet in order to be successfully persisted with the CollectionEditor:

1. The collection must implement the `IList` interface (inheriting from `System.Collections.CollectionBase` is in most of the cases the best option).
2. The collection must have an Indexer property.
3. The collection class must implement one or both of the following methods: `Add` and/or `AddRange`

So I created a class 'ImageItem' containing

- an image

  ```cs
  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(Image), null)]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public Image Picture {
    get { return m_Picture; }
    set { m_Picture = value; }
  }
  ```
- a name (optional)

  ```cs
  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public string Name {
    get { return m_Name; }
    set { m_Name = value; }
  }
  ```
- a value (optional)

  ```cs
  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(int), "-1")]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public int Value {
    get { return m_Value; }
    set { m_Value = value; }
  }
  ```

and a collection 'ImageCollection' holding instances of this class according to the conditions mentioned above:

1. `public class ImageCollection : CollectionBase`
2. `public ImageItem this[int i]`
3. `public ImageItem Add(ImageItem item)`

Then I created a control containing only this collection, initialized with one image:

```cs
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public MyControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ImageCollection   m_MyImageCollection = new ImageCollection()
    { new ImageItem(0, "Failure", Properties.Resources.Cross), new ImageItem(1, "OK", Properties.Resources.Tickmark) };

    [Browsable(true), Category("A Test"), DisplayName("Image Collection (ImageCollection)"), Description("Edit image collection")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public ImageCollection    MyImageCollection {
        get { return m_MyImageCollection; }
    }
}
```

After compiling this code the designer shows that property. Now it is possible to add images using the common designer GUI controls.

[image: MyControl]

[image: Edit image collection]

[image: Select Resource]

I tried to change the default images compiled into this control when using it on my form, but I recognized, that the designer cannot remove content. It only stores the 'Add' action. So I modified the code to search within the collection for another item with the same ID. If there is one available, that instance is removed and replaced with the new one. Therefore I had to implement the `AddRange` method too.

```cs
public ImageItem Add(ImageItem item) {
    for(int i = 0; i < InnerList.Count; i++) {
        if(InnerList[i] is ImageItem) {
            if(((ImageItem)InnerList[i]).Value == item.Value) {
                InnerList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    this.InnerList.Add(item);
    return item;
}

public void AddRange(ImageItem[] array) {
    foreach(ImageItem item in array) {
        Add(item);
    }
}
```

So my final classes are:

[image: My Classes]

```cs
public class ImageItem {
  private int               m_Value   = -1;
  private string            m_Name    = "ImageItem";
  private Image             m_Picture = null;

  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(int), "-1")]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public int Value {
    get { return m_Value; }
    set { m_Value = value; }
  }

  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public string Name {
    get { return m_Name; }
    set { m_Name = value; }
  }

  [Category("ImageItem")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(Image), null)]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public Image Picture {
    get { return m_Picture; }
    set { m_Picture = value; }
  }

  public ImageItem() { }

  public ImageItem(int value, string name, Image image) {
    this.m_Value   = value;
    this.m_Name    = name;
    this.m_Picture = image;
  }
}
```

And `ImageCollection`:

```cs
public class ImageCollection : CollectionBase {
  public ImageCollection() {}

  public ImageItem this[int i]
  {
    get { return (ImageItem)this.InnerList[i]; }
    set { this.InnerList[i] = value; }
  }

  public ImageItem Add(ImageItem item) {
    for(int i = 0; i < InnerList.Count; i++) {
      if(InnerList[i] is ImageItem) {
        if(((ImageItem)InnerList[i]).Value == item.Value) {
          InnerList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
      }
    }
    this.InnerList.Add(item);
    return item;
  }

  public void AddRange(ImageItem[] array) {
    foreach(ImageItem item in array) {
      Add(item);
    }
  }

  public void Remove(ImageItem item) {
    this.InnerList.Remove(item);
  }

  public bool Contains(ImageItem item) {
    return this.InnerList.Contains(item);
  }

  public ImageItem[] GetValues() {
    ImageItem[] item= new ImageItem[this.InnerList.Count];
    this.InnerList.CopyTo(0, item, 0, this.InnerList.Count);
    return item;
  }

  protected override void OnInsert(int index, object value) {
    base.OnInsert(index, value);
  }
}
```